# Jackson JsonParseException:expected a valid value

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

> I am getting below exception while parsing  string to object. can
>   anyone suggest me ,why i am getting this error ?

```
 org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('A' (code 65)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
     at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3f203f2; line: 1, column: 2]
```

> FYI : I have already tried with given below option.but it's not
>   helped.

```
_jsonMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES,true);
```

> Refer given below JSONContent:

```
   {
    "date": 1468834383007,
    "seq": 2,
    "type": "CPT",
    "code": "31237",
    "bit": "Not Applicable",
    "desc": "Hello/world ; with chorme,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\thelicopeer or one (two theree)",
    "qun": 2,
    "ty": "VS",
    "dstat": 1463682600000,
    "dend": 1463682600000,
    "prmInd": true,
    "deletable": false,
    "mar": false,
    "show": true,
    "uid": "10ab5ad8-a472-4be6-9e9d-a7c9589bb201",
    "compprcstr": "31237CPTNot hello/world,surgical;withbiopsy,one(two)2",
    "short": "NA",
    "tastsr": "CPT",
    "bui": false,
    "desFee": "Java\/oralceendo,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\orlaceor two (f)",
    "pce": "31237",
    "desTrun": "Hello/java ,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\Orlace or Java (three)",
    "sasStr": "Visit(s)",
    "codE": false,
    "fsDate": "05/20/2016",
    "feDate": "05/20/2016",
    "primary": false,
    "servTy": "VS",
    "doS": true,
    "proead": false,
    "ambulance": false,
    "lilatehell": "NA",
    "modifList": ["NA"],
    "prwithSeq": "31237CPT2",
    "dirty": true,
    "dirtySince": false,
    "entityName": "com.neopo.corba.model.hospital.Check",
    "skip1": false
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post json, from error it seems somewhere you have not added correct data. Please validate your JSON first.

Comment: Please edit your question. As of right now it lacks formatting as well as your code.

Comment: I guess your json content is not properly formed

Comment: First of all, you question is not properly formatter. I tried validating your JSON at www.jsonlint.com and you have an error in you JSON format. 
`Error: Parse error on line 21:
...: false, "desFee": "Java\/oralceendo,\n
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'`
You can see that yourself on that website.

Comment: By just using an online JSON validator, I noticed you have an error on this line: `"desTrun": "Hello/java ,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\Orlace or Java (three)",`

Comment: @Sajib and Olar , Actually i am getting the valid Json message from www.jsonlint.com

Comment: @VasanthDha, buddy, the JSON you posted is clearly giving error on jsonlint.

Answer (score 0):

json format is incorrect in

> \t\O

change

```
"desTrun": "Hello/java ,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\Orlace or Java (three)",
```

to

```
 "desTrun": "Hello/java ,\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Orlace or Java (three)",
```